# embed ruby code in C

Tags: c, ruby

I know there's severals post about this, but i'm stack

here's my C code

```
#include </usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 ruby_init();
 rb_eval_string("puts 'hello'");
 ruby_finalize();
 return 0;
 }
```

i've got the following error when compile it in sublime text 2

```
In file included from /Users/pierrebaille/Code/Ruby/embedRuby/embedRubyFirst.c:1:
/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1481:24: error: ruby/subst.h: No such file or directory         
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not hard-code the full path of a header file like

`#include </usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h>`

proper is

`#include <ruby.h>`

and told your gcc to search the header file via CFLAGS and libariy via LD_FLAGS, simply command without makefile could be:

`gcc  -o demo.exe -I/path/to/ruby/headers rubydemo.c -L/path/to/ruby/lib  -lruby-libary-name`

Comment: thank you, demo.exe? if i am on OSX i should use something else no? like demo.rbo maybe? sorry i'm a beginner. I think i should take time to learn more about gcc...

Comment: could be, I am not sure, no have OS-X in hand.

Answer (score 3):

One of you files you're including in turn includes `ruby/subst.h`, , but it appears that `ruby` is not in your path, which is why you have this in your code:

```
#include </usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h>
```

Instead of hardcoding paths you should simply add "/some_path/" to your compiler path(s) setting, where `some_path` contains the folder `ruby` as a child.  Now your own include turns into:

```
#include <ruby/ruby.h>
```

Comment: i don't know how to add path to my compiler... but i've moved the ruby 1.9.1 folder into my usr/include folder wich is, i think, in the compiler path. no?

Comment: when i just replace my hardcoded include with #include <ruby/ruby.h>

Comment: it give me this error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rb_eval_string", referenced from:
      _main in ccqmMJJ3.o
  "_ruby_finalize", referenced from:
      _main in ccqmMJJ3.o
  "_ruby_init", referenced from:
      _main in ccqmMJJ3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]